# MySQL: CONCAT с условием

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Есть таблица:

```
id|title|description
-------
1|title1|title1
2|title2|title2
3|title3|ololo
4|title4|title4
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли одном запросом добыть такие данные:

```
id|title
-------
1|title1
2|title2
3|title3 ololo
4|title4
```

Благодарю за ответы.

С уважением, Дмитрий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так:

```
select if(title=description,title, concat(title," ",description)) as title
from tab
```